# Searching records in database by list of Ids

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq

I have a list of ids (itemID's) which I pass to the query like following:

```
 using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                ctx.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                var storeItems = ctx.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(y => y.StoreID == 223250).ToList();
                var idList = storeItems.Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
                var storeTransactions = ctx.ItemTransactions.AsNoTracking().Where(r => idList.Contains(r.Id.Value)).ToList();
                return Json("Ok");
            }
```

To sum it up quickly... the StoreItems list for example 1001 item in this case...

And by passing the 1001 item id to fetch the item transactions I get back result of

265000 records...

The two tables aren't connected by any relation but the Id column is indexed to improve the result...

However, the last query performance is absolutely terrible and takes more than a minute to fully finish selecting all records, even with all the tweaks I've added to it to speed it up, but it still didn't help....

Does anyone knows if there's still  something that I'm missing to speed things up on this last query when fetching transactions for items?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: does really 265000 records exist for 1001 ids? or there are any duplications in record?

Comment: @er-mfahhgk it's 265000 indeed :/

Comment: It would like to see relationship of tables. one more thing, why you pulling all columns as using ToList().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> The two tables aren't connected by any relation

Well apparently there is some relation. You expect that the `ItemTranaction.Id.Value` has sometimes the value of `Item.Id`

You get all Items with a StoreId equal to 223250. Get the Id from these items items. Give me all ItemTransactions that have a Id.Value that is also in the fetched Ids.

In other words:

> **Requirement**: Give me all ItemTransactions, that have a value for itemTransaction.Id.Value equal to one of the Ids of all Items with StoreId equal to 223250

Your query will be much faster if you do it in one query:

```
int storeId = 223250;

var result = dbContext.ItemTransactions
  .Join(dbContext.Items.Where(item => item.StoreId == storeId),
  itemTransaction => itemTransaction.Id.Value,
  item => item.Id,
  (itemtransaction, item) => itemTransaction)
```

In words:

- Join the itemtransaction with the items that have a StoreId equal to storId.
- From every itemTransaction take the itemTransaction.Id.Value,
- From every item take the Id
- when these values are equal, take the itemTransaction and the item to create a result
- this result is the itemTransaction

You didn't say so, but I think that item.Id is the primary key. That ensures that there are no two items with the same Id, and thus all remaining itemTransactions are unique. Distinct is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you get the list of actionable IDs to memory and then use it to query again. This means EF will translate it as a simple `IN` query with all the IDs hardcoded. Actually I even suspect that because the number of 265000 records is too high, it will actually first get all the `ItemTransactions` from the DB and then do the query in memory. This causes the bad performance. But a simple change will make the performance significantly better:

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var storeItems = ctx.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(y => y.StoreID == 223250);
    var idList = storeItems.Select(y => y.Id); //removed ToList on this and previous line
    var storeTransactions = ctx.ItemTransactions.AsNoTracking()
                               .Where(r => idList.Contains(r.Id.Value)).ToList();
    return Json("Ok");
}
```

The only change I have made is to remove `ToList()` calls in your code. This will mean `idList` is a `IQueryable<int>` which EF can understand and instead of executing it first, it will use it as a subquery or `JOIN` in the last statement - which will have significantly better performance.

Also consider if you actually need the `ItemTransactions` instances as a whole or you can use a projection with `Select` to query only the properties you actually need. This would decrease the amount of data that must be transfered between your app and the database.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! :) I understand what you intended with removal of "toList" ... Thus reducing the load on database without executing the query itself for items... But for the transactions it's still taking about 65 seconds... :/

Comment: That is really weird... How many records are eventually returned?

Comment: @Marin Zikmund 265757 to be exact

Comment: How long does it take if you just use plain `Count()` on the query instead of `ToList()`?

Comment: 421 milisecond in this case ^^

Comment: var storeTransactions = ctx.ItemTransactions.AsNoTracking().Count(r => idList.Contains(r.Id.Value));

Answer (score 1):

No need to disable `LazyLoadingEnabled` option on database and make use of `AsQueryable` so that `ids` wont be in memory. I would recommended to use `join` in this case.

Try this:

```
using ( var ctx = new MyEntities() )
{
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    var idList = ctx.Items.AsNoTracking().Where( y => y.StoreID == 223250 ).Select( y => y.Id ).AsQueryable();

    var storeTransactions = ctx.ItemTransactions.AsNoTracking().Where( r => idList.Contains( r.Id.Value ) ).ToList();

    return Json( "Ok" );
}
```

Comment: I think `AsQueryable` is actually unnecessary. The query is `IQueryable<int>`, unless you call `ToList()` on it.